# Yii2 captcha provides image link & verify but image doesnot appear

Tags: captcha, yii2-advanced-app, active-form

I am trying to use yii2 captcha but it does not appear . Verify works absolutely fine. My code given below

**Controller**

```
 public function actions()
   {
     return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
        ],
     ];
   }
```

*Model*

```
 public $captcha;
 public function rules()
 {
    return [
        [['yourname', 'youremail', 'contactnumber', 'comment','captcha'], 'required'],
        [['comment'], 'string'],

        ['captcha', 'captcha'],
        [['youremail'],'email'],
        [['timestampp','cv'], 'safe'],
        [['yourname', 'youremail', 'contactnumber', 'highsteducation', 'institutename', 'passinguear', 'keyskills', 'yearofexperience', 'expectedsalary'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['comment'], 'string','min' => 20 ,'max' => 200]

    ];
 }
```

**View**

```
 <?= $form->field($career_model, 'captcha')->widget(\yii\captcha\Captcha::classname()) ?>
```

*With error*

```
<div>
   <img id="career-captcha-image" src="/basetextile/site/captcha?v=58f5fadc92838" alt=""> <input type="text" id="career-captcha" class="form-control" name="Career[captcha]">
   <p class="help-block help-block-error">The verification code is incorrect.</p>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Ojy.png)

Answer (score 0):

If everything is okay in your code then, it seems that you have problem with your extensions installed.

1. If you don't see captcha, check Yii2 requirments by typing in
   command line in the root directory of project:
   **php requirements.php**
2. Either GD PHP extension with FreeType support or ImageMagick PHP extension with PNG support is required for image CAPTCHA.
3. If above extensions are not enabled, you need to enable them.

Comment: It shows warning for ImageMagick PHP extension. How i solve it

Comment: @Destroyer.0211 : You need to install it, refer this link http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php